# Не могу задать стили элементу который имеется в двух классов

Tags: html, css

Я использую такой код для классов *.register, .login* но код с *элементом* **а** *не работает* , *без элемента* **а** *все работает правильно* .

```
.register, .login a {
   text-decoration: none;
 }
```

Как задать стили *элементу* **а**, каждого из классов ?

Отмечу что  классы *.register и  .login* принадлежат разным элементам.

```css
.register, .login a {
       text-decoration: none;
       color: red;
     }
```

```html
<div class="register">
   <a href="#">register</a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="login">
   <a href="#">login</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: html покажите, чтобы понимать что у вас там

Comment: зпт уберите ...

Comment: html  очень большой нечего понятно не будет но я сделал правку к вопросу который надеюсь поможет понять

Comment: запятая не пречом

Comment: Можно просто кусочки, где используется .login a
Возможно какой-то стиль перекрывает стили для ссылок

Comment: Добавил упрошенную версию HTML

Comment: Если смотреть в чистом виде, то все нормально.
https://jsfiddle.net/ge5vdbat/ Значит где-то перекрываются стили

Comment: Не все не нормально просто в jsfiddle  классы били одинаковыми теперь я изменил.

Comment: Не совсем понял. Вопрос решился или нет? По ссылке выше на jsfiddle все правильно отображается. Там классы правильно прописаны и стили для них

Comment: .refister это блок , у него нету text-decoration а вот ссылка уже имеет text-decoration вот и надо писать явно что в .register a {одни стили }; login a{другие стили}

Comment: Все по прежнему не нормально  посмотрите обновленный более наглядный jsFiDDLE

Comment: Сделал чуть более развернутый пример. https://jsfiddle.net/ge5vdbat/4/

Comment: Спасибо  все правильно теперь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не работает потому что ты стайлиш блок а нужно ссылку.

```
.register a,
.login a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: red;
 }
```